# I have a datagrid I am getting an exception saying that the items Collection must be empty when I try to reset the datagrid's items source

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is the method that runs and it is fired on the start of the program and when a button is clicked to refresh the list (it pulls its information from a SQL server database that other people running the time log program can add time to this is just the master list of all the time logs)

```
private void viewPeopleTimLog()
{
    string message;
    //Datagrid cleared out
    dtgPeopleTimLog.ItemsSource = null;

    //List of TimeLog Objects.
    //It passes back out a blank string if nothing goes wrong and passes 
    //back out the out the error message if something goes wrong
    PeopleTimeLogList logList = new PeopleTimeLogList(out message);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) //Everything is fine
    {
        dtgPeopleTimLog.ItemsSource = logList; //Line it fails on
    }
    else
    {
         //Code to print the exception message here
    }
}
```

TimeLog object contains
   1. The person's id # stored as an int.
   2. The person's name stored as a string.
   3. The person's comment about the work that was accomplished stored as a string.
   4. The date the time was logged stored as a DateTime.
   5. The amount of time logged by the person stored as a double.

And here is the xaml code for the datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgPeopleTimLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="404" 
          Width="1000" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Logged" Binding="{Binding DateLogged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID #" Binding="{Binding IDNumber}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding PersonName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time Logged" Binding="{Binding TimeLogged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Width" Value="540"/>
                 </Style>
                 </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
              </DataGridTextColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Am I missing something here? I have looked and looked and nothing appears to match my situation. I have all my columns bound from the object to the datagrid, and I am clearing out the itemssource before I get the list of TimeLog objects and place that as the itemssource. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: try set a breakpoint on `dtgPeopleTimLog.ItemsSource = logList;` and check in debugger the content of `dtgPeopleTimLog.Items` property. there should not be any items

Comment: You may get this exception when you've put anything inside the `<DataGrid>` tag that is not a DataGrid property (like `DataGrid.Columns`) and is hence implictly handled as an item. Is what you are showing here your actual XAML?

Comment: Yes it is @Clemens it is. And I have done the exact code (different object, but same idea) before with another program and it is not causing any issues

Comment: @ASh I did that and there were not any items

Comment: As a note, this derived collection class constructor looks odd. Why wouldn't you just throw and catch an exception instead of returning an error message as out parameter? But if you do that, you should always assign the newly created collection to the ItemsSource property. In case of an error, it would just be empty. There wouldn't be any need to set ItemsSource to null in advance.

Comment: I do throw and catch the error, but I do it in the constructor because it does a connection to a remote database so I already have a try catch around the database connection related code (the opening of the connection, the adding of the parameters, and the execution of the reader), because all of that is done I need the connection to the database to be closed even if the error occurs so throwing a new exception to be caught outside the constructor the database connection would not get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out based on comments to question. The answer is

```
private void viewPeopleTimLog()
{
    string message;

    dtgPeopleTimLog.ItemsSource = null;

    PeopleTimeLogList logList = new PeopleTimeLogList(out message);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) //Everything is fine
    {
        dtgPeopleTimLog.ItemsSource = logList;
    }
    else
    {
         //Code to print the exception message here
    }
}
```

And the XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgPeopleTimLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="404" 
          Width="1000" />
```

This apparently was an issue with the explicitly defined columns so I removed the explicitly defined columns and it worked. I don't need the special header information so this works.

Comment: Let me clarify this code is just dynamically creating the columns of the data grid and filling it in. This being done allows for the button to refresh the data because explicitly defining the columns restricted the data.